# Trying to Count Number of DOM child elements from an XML file

Tags: javascript, xml, dom

I am trying to write some simple code to display the number of immediate child elements there are for 2 XML files. Here is the best code I have come up with so far.

```
<script>
    var xmlDoc = loadXMLDoc("W6 XML and JS.xml");       
    x = xmlDoc.documentElement.childNodes;
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {

    }
    document.write("There are " + i + " immediate child elements directly under the root element.<br />");
</script>
```

So for XML input on these I have this. I am trying to get it to show 2 child elements and not all elements.

```html
<dataroot>
  <Courses>
    <Department>CIS</Department>
    <CourseNumber>141</CourseNumber>
    <Title>intro to access</Title>
    <Description>db stuff</Description>
    <Credits>5</Credits>
    <Prerequisites>108, 123</Prerequisites>
    <DateAdded>2011-07-01T00:00:00</DateAdded>
  </Courses>
  <Courses>
    <Department>cap</Department>
    <CourseNumber>102</CourseNumber>
    <Title>Nutrition for the Food Service Professional</Title>
    <Description>Nutrition for the Food Service Professional</Description>
    <Credits>5</Credits>
    <DateAdded>2001-01-01T00:00:00</DateAdded>
  </Courses>
</dataroot>
```

I know there is a simple answer I am just not able to find it right now. any help is appreciated ( This noob thanks you)

Comment: do you mean there are n number of Courses in your xml and you need only first 2 Course elements?

Comment: I think you are right. I am looking for the immediate elements off the root element. so the above is 2 courses and below is 7 childnodes coming from the root. 

So this example the answer should be 7:
`<?xml version=”1.0”?>
<Course>
<Department>CIS</Department>
<CourseNumber>141</CourseNumber>
<Title>intro to access</Title>
<Description>db stuff</Description>
<Credits>5</Credits>
<Prerequisites>108, 123</Prerequisites>
<DateAdded>2011-07-01T00:00:00</DateAdded>
</Course>`

That formatting is bad, so sorry. The elements between Courses elements are children of the root element.

Comment: Still too fuzzy. what is your output given the XML? Do you just need to print  "There are 2 immediate child elements directly under the root element.<br />" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function getElementCount() {
  var doc = `<Course>
  <Department>CIS</Department>
  <CourseNumber>141</CourseNumber>
  <Title>intro to access</Title>
  <Description>db stuff</Description>
  <Credits>5</Credits>
  <Prerequisites>108, 123</Prerequisites>
  <DateAdded>2011-07-01T00:00:00</DateAdded>
</Course>`;
  var parser = new DOMParser(),
    xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(doc, "text/xml"),
    elementCount = xmlDoc.documentElement.childElementCount;

  console.log(`There are ${elementCount} immediate child elements directly under the root element.`);
}
getElementCount();
```

If  you are looking to just print the documents immediate child element count, you just need to check on the ChildElementCount as mentioned in the snippet.

```js
function getElementCount() {
  var doc = `<dataroot>
  <Courses>
    <Department>CIS</Department>
    <CourseNumber>141</CourseNumber>
    <Title>intro to access</Title>
    <Description>db stuff</Description>
    <Credits>5</Credits>
    <Prerequisites>108, 123</Prerequisites>
    <DateAdded>2011-07-01T00:00:00</DateAdded>
  </Courses>
  <Courses>
    <Department>cap</Department>
    <CourseNumber>102</CourseNumber>
    <Title>Nutrition for the Food Service Professional</Title>
    <Description>Nutrition for the Food Service Professional</Description>
    <Credits>5</Credits>
    <DateAdded>2001-01-01T00:00:00</DateAdded>
  </Courses>
</dataroot>`;
  var parser = new DOMParser(),
    xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(doc, "text/xml"),
    elementCount = xmlDoc.documentElement.childElementCount;

  console.log(`There are ${elementCount} immediate child elements directly under the root element.`);
}
getElementCount();
```

You could do this in your code

```js
var xmlDoc = loadXMLDoc("W6 XML and JS.xml");
x = xmlDoc.documentElement.childElementCount;

document.write("There are " + x + " immediate child elements directly under the root element.<br />");
```

Comment: I believe your answer would work if I was using jQuery however I am using Javascript and I am getting errors when trying to compile still. Thank you for your replies though.

Comment: There is no jQuery here. it is in pure JS. would you mind sharing the error?

Comment: So close. It worked for the first file. which it showed 2 but it is only telling me one for this file. 
`
<Course>
      <Department>CIS</Department>
      <CourseNumber>141</CourseNumber>
      <Title>intro to access</Title>
      <Description>db stuff</Description>
      <Credits>5</Credits>
      <Prerequisites>108, 123</Prerequisites>
      <DateAdded>2011-07-01T00:00:00</DateAdded>
</Course>
`

Comment: I must just be having cache issue then.

Comment: I am using Visual Studios to compile. the difference is that When using the snippet on here it work. but when I try to run on site it shows nothing. I think it is because i don't have the parse stuff in there like you do in the snippet

Comment: Even when you use var xmlDoc = loadXMLDoc("W6 XML and JS.xml");
x = xmlDoc.documentElement.childElementCount; It should return the exact results. Parser is something I used for running the code here on SO.  This particular piece of code, xmlDoc.documentElement.childElementCount is a client side API and is available in all browsers. I feel, when you run this code on site as you mentioned, should be because of laodXML not properly loading the files.